# Custom allocator with hard limits

Tags: c++11, allocator

I want to replace some code that uses `boost::interprocess` shared memory. One advantage of shared memory is that you can impose limits on the maximum amount of memory it can use. I'm looking for a custom allocator, based off `std::allocator` that can do this.

Only particular classes in the program will use this allocator, everything else uses the defaulted `std::allocator` and are only limited by available RAM.

I'm trying to write one of my own but I'm running into issues, mainly with how to share state among the allocator copies that are created by STL containers. State includes the number of free bytes remaining and the maximum size the allocator can use. I thought I could get away with making them `thread_local` but then several different instances of the same class will all allocate and deallocate from the same limited heap, which is not what I want. I'm beginning to think it's not possible, hence this question here. Neither contiguous allocation nor performance are major requirements for now.

The hard limit on the memory size cannot be a template parameter either, it's read from a config file.

Edit: The issue with sharing state is that some containers call the default constructor of the allocator type. Obviously this constructor cannot easily know anything about the outside world even if `shared_ptr` is used it will be nullptr initialised. For example, look at the source code for `std::string::clear`

`g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`

Comment: What's wrong with the stdlib's normal stateful allocator support?:

Comment: @Puppy From my understanding, the allocators are copied and so if the first copy has 50 bytes remaining at the time of the copy, then allocates 10 more bytes, the second copy will still think that 50 are remaining. I could be doing something completely stupid.

Comment: You share state between allocators the same way you do between any other objects. Have each allocator store a pointer, or perhaps `shared_ptr`, to the object managing said state.

Comment: Yes turns out I was being stupid

Answer (score 1):

After following the hints above I came up with this which seems to work ok for POD types, but things fall apart when I try to make a Vector or Map that uses String:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

struct SharedState
{
    SharedState()
    : m_maxSize(0),
      m_bytesRemaining(0)
    {
    }

    SharedState(std::size_t maxSize)
        : m_maxSize(maxSize),
          m_bytesRemaining(maxSize)
    {
    }

    void allocate(std::size_t bytes) const {
        if (m_bytesRemaining < bytes) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }

        m_bytesRemaining -= bytes;
    }

    void deallocate(std::size_t bytes) const {
        m_bytesRemaining += bytes;
    }

    std::size_t getBytesRemaining() const {
        return m_bytesRemaining;
    }

    const std::size_t m_maxSize;
    mutable std::atomic<std::size_t> m_bytesRemaining;
};


// --------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class BaseLimitedAllocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:
    using size_type =  std::size_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;

    template <typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef BaseLimitedAllocator<U> other;
    };

    BaseLimitedAllocator() noexcept = default;

    BaseLimitedAllocator(std::size_t maxSize) noexcept
    :  m_state(new SharedState(maxSize)) {
    }

    BaseLimitedAllocator(const BaseLimitedAllocator& other) noexcept {
       m_state = other.m_state;
    }

    template <typename U>
    BaseLimitedAllocator(const BaseLimitedAllocator<U>& other) noexcept {
        m_state = other.m_state;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = nullptr) {
        m_state->allocate(n * sizeof(T));
        return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
        std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n);
        m_state->deallocate(n * sizeof(T));
    }

public:
    std::shared_ptr<SharedState> m_state;   // This must be public for the rebind copy constructor.
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator==(const BaseLimitedAllocator<T>&, const BaseLimitedAllocator<U>&) {
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator!=(const BaseLimitedAllocator<T>&, const BaseLimitedAllocator<U>&) {
    return false;
}


struct LimitedAllocator : public BaseLimitedAllocator<char>
{
    LimitedAllocator(std::size_t maxSize)
    :  BaseLimitedAllocator<char>(maxSize) {
    }

    template <typename U>
    using Other = typename BaseLimitedAllocator<char>::template rebind<U>::other;
};

// -----------------------------------------
// Example usage:

class SomeClass
{
public:
    using String = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, LimitedAllocator::Other<char>>;

    template <typename T>
    using Vector = std::vector<T, LimitedAllocator::Other<T>>;

    template <typename K, typename V>
    using Map = std::map<K, V, std::less<K>, LimitedAllocator::Other<std::pair<const K, V>>>;

    Complex()
    :  allocator(256),
       s(allocator),
       v(allocator),
       m(std::less<int>(), allocator) // Cannot only specify the allocator. Annoying.
    {
    }

    const LimitedAllocator allocator;
    String s;
    Vector<int> v;
    Map<int, String> m;
};
```